# Read serial port: how to interrupt read blocking operation

Tags: perl

I have a PERL app that launches a thread for serial communication...
I am using lib use Device::SerialPort;

```
while($bRun)
{
    print "Waiting for serial port data...";

    my ($count,$msg)=$SerialPort->read(255); # will read _up to_ 255 chars

    if ($count > 0) 
    {
            #Process
    }

    #sleep(1);
}
```

But it must be possible to stop that thread even during read operation.

I already have a method to put bRun to false but how to unblock thread if it is in the read operation?

Thanks a lot

Alex

Answer (score 0):

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Device-SerialPort/SerialPort.pm isn't very clear on how to do non-blocking I/O.  It sounds like it uses perl's `select` internally to see if characters are available.

I haven't written a multi-threaded perl program before.  Can you send a signal to another thread, which would interrupt a system call?

If you just want to stop the thread, not get it to break out of a read and do something else, that should be easier.  Just kill it normally.

Comment: It seems that signals are process context and not thread context... I would like to stop thread because that will be code after while that must be executed after read breaking...

Comment: @Alexandre: I haven't looked into things in perl, but the underlying Unix system-call interface certainly allows sending signals to threads.  See http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_kill